# Double % in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a `Makefile` that will generate a "rectangular" set of output files from a single source file. Imagine we have a single SVG file and we want to compile it to many PNG files. The creation of the PNG files is controlled by two parameters (hence the "rectangular" word) -- resolution (high, low) and color (colorful, black-white). The simplest `Makefile` that creates such PNG files out of a SVG file could look like this:

```
img-highres-color.png: img.svg
    convert --highres --color --output img-highres-color.png img.svg

img-highres-bw.png: img.svg
    convert --highres --bw --output img-highres-color.png img.svg

img-lowres-color.png: img.svg
    convert --lowres --color --output img-highres-color.png img.svg

img-lowres-bw.png: img.svg
    convert --lowres --bw --output img-highres-color.png img.svg
```

The next step is to create a static pattern rule that uses `%`. I was able to come up with this:

```
RESOLUTIONS = highres lowres
COLORS = color bw

PNG_FILES = $(foreach r, $(RESOLUTIONS), $(foreach c, $(COLORS), img-$(r)-$(c).png))

$(filter img-highres-%.png, $(PNG_FILES)): img-highres-%.png: img.svg
    convert --highres --$* --output img-highres-$*.png img.svg

$(filter img-lowres-%.png, $(PNG_FILES)): img-lowres-%.png: img.svg
    convert --lowres --$* --output img-lowres-$*.png img.svg
```

Finally, I'd like to create a single static pattern rule, but this would require using a double `%`, like this:

```
RESOLUTIONS = highres lowres
COLORS = color bw

PNG_FILES = $(foreach r, $(RESOLUTIONS), $(foreach c, $(COLORS), img-$(r)-$(c).png))

$(filter img-%-%.png, $(PNG_FILES)): img-%-%.png: img.svg
    convert --$* --$* --output img-$*-$*.png img.svg
```

This of course doesn't work. Is it possible to write a single rule to achieve this?

The situation above is a simplified description of my real situation. The important thing is that the value of `RESOLUTIONS` and `COLORS` variables isn't known in advance. Also, can you provide a solution general enough to handle more than two dimensions? In the example above the third dimension could be the file type - PNG, JPG, GIF etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(eval)` here:

```
RESOLUTIONS=highres lowres
COLORS=color bw
PNG_FILES = $(foreach r, $(RESOLUTIONS), $(foreach c, $(COLORS), img-$(r)-$(c).png))

all: $(PNG_FILES)

# Make the rules for converting the svg into each variant.

define mkrule
img-$1-$2.png: img.svg
    @convert --$1 --$2 --output $$@ $$<
endef
$(foreach color,$(COLORS),$(foreach res,$(RESOLUTIONS),$(eval $(call mkrule,$(res),$(color)))))
```

`$(eval)` allows you to dynamically construct and inject makefile fragments into the makefile being parsed.  You should be able to extend this with as many different dimensions as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `%` and "unpack" the `$*` with text manipulation functions like so:

```
$(filter img-%.png, $(PNG_FILES)): img-%.png: img.svg
    convert $(addprefix --,$(subst -, ,$*)) --output $@ $<
```

The `$(subst)` splits `$*` into words at the `-`, and the `$(addprefix)` acts on each word in turn. Bonus: The same rule will work for more than 2 dimensions too, as long as none of the flags you're using contains a `-` :-)